# How do I reverse this Jquery and turn it into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how to reverse Jquery into Javascript. Here is the line of code I have so far

```
$('#toggle-all').on('change', this.toggleAll.bind(this));
```

From what I see, I can set it equal to a variable, then add an event listener

```
const toggleAll = document.getElementById('toggle-all');
toggleAll.addEventListener('change', function () {

})
```

What I don't know is what to do with the code after the word "change" the `this.toggleAll.bind(this)` part.

Note the code is a method within an object and `toggleAll` is defined with this

```
toggleAll: function (e) {
    var isChecked = $(e.target).prop('checked');

    this.todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        todo.completed = isChecked;
    });

    this.render();
},
```

Comment: "What I don't know is what to do with the code after the word change? the this.toggleAll.bind(this)" — Why do anything with it?

Comment: You should give enough context so we can see what `this` is in your original code.

Comment: all my jquery code is inside of an object called var App

Comment: Also, I tried to keep it this.toggleAll.bind(this) after the change, but my code broke and basically doesn't work

Comment: If you want to use the same function as a callback just use it as the second argument like you do with jquery, ie `addEventListener('change',this.toggleAll.bind(this))`

Comment: ah okay it looks like that works. I think the problem was I had an extra }) which made my code not work eariler